# macOS Terminal - How to use osascript while doing SSH

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, notifications

If I use this string in Terminal

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Line3" with title "Line1" subtitle "Line2" sound name "Hero"'
```

it correctly display a notification but if I launch it while doing SSH connection with a server obviously it doesn't work because the machine is different. So, how can I use this command while doing a SSH connection?

Comment: Any solution? Sorry for bumping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2nd Terminal window: Ctrl-Mouse click on Terminal icon, New Window, run command.